# How can a wavefront sensor be validated?

Tags: optics

Having a wavefront sensor (e.g. of Shack-Hartmann-type), what are relatively easy methods for validating its measurement results?

I have tried inserting lenses into the light path. Unfortunately, I can't see (nor quantify) any obvious contractions of spots. I think this can be explained by the sensors f=17500 microns and lenslet diameter of 300 microns which makes it sensitive with respect to lens parameters and position. As a hobbyist, both are not completely under my control.[image]

Comment: What kind of focal did you try? Do you know how large of a contraction you should expect?

Comment: From ray optics only, the contraction factor in the distance between the dots should be about $alpha = (f_{\mathrm{lens}} - f)/f_{\mathrm{lens}}$, where $f_{\mathrm{lens}}$ is the focal of the lens you put in front of the device (assuming it is set just in front of the device), and $f=17.5\,\mathrm{mm}$ is the focal of the lenslets. So if your lens has too large of a focal, it will be hard to notice any change.

Comment: Hi @QuantumApple, I thought matching the focals would be a good idea so that the spots don't get placed on image sensor pixels beneath other lenslets. In fact it seems not to be a wise choice. Can you share the reasoning behind this contraction factor? Many thanks!

Comment: I added a ray optics' simulation with ricktu288's tool@github with matching focals. To me it looks like such a setup would be great for seeing variations of the focal spots.

Comment: The distance from the lens you insert to the array of lenslet is also important. Is it possible that you provide a drawing of your setup with the approximate distances and focal used? And if you suddenly put a lens (by hand) with $f \simeq 10\, \mathrm{cm}$ or less just in front of the sensor, do you see any difference in the position of the spots (you should be able to see it)?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I needed to arrange the setup again and realized I had to re-state the problem at hand a little. The problem with inserting a convex or concave lens is that it pretty much scales the spot pattern. The scaling is not easy to interpret as a wavefront distortion as the spots cannot be assigned (e.g. by selfmade centroid finding or my own eyes) to any fixed lenslet any more during the insertion. Would this work better with a lens only having some astigmatism or coma?